# why am I getting Exec format error when I am writing my linux service?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, spring-boot, service

I am writing a linux service to deploy my springboot web app as a service.
Here is the service file `springboot.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Webapp Java REST Service

[Service]
User=ubuntu
# The configuration file application.properties should be here:

#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu

#path to executable. 
#executable is a bash script which calls jar file
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/spring-start

SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My script file `spring-start.sh`

```
sudo java -jar "/home/ubuntu/FirstWebAppWithoutDB.jar"
```

I also gave execution permission to the spring-start.sh by `chmod u+x spring-start.sh`

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable springboot.service

sudo systemctl start springboot

sudo systemctl status springboot
```

Unfortunately the service fails with error Exec format error:

```
springboot.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Jul 14 07:39:56 ip-172-31-40-71 systemd[10075]: springboot.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/ubuntu/spring-start.sh: Exec format error
```

Comment: Add a shebang to spring-start.sh?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

add shebang to the script

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo java -jar "/home/ubuntu/FirstWebAppWithoutDB.jar"
```

and execution permission

```
chmod +x spring-start.sh
```

Comment: And add the full path to the script you are calling in your system service file, best with `ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/ubuntu/spring-start`

Comment: do i have to add this in 'springboot.service' file ???

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud Depends on what you mean by "this". If you're talking about the comment from rubo77, yes, the ExecStart line should have the full paths; if you're talking about adding the shebang, then no - the shebang goes in the shell script itself, not the springboot.service file.

Comment: holly molly, i spent an hour resolving this issue(. thanks !

Answer (score 14):

Your **spring-start.sh** is executed by *bash* you need to explicit your ExecStart in **springboot.service** file like this :
**ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/ubuntu/spring-start.sh**

Comment: how can I use this for python3 ??

Comment: @Hamid you do the same and #!/bin/python3 or whatever the path to python3 in your system

Answer (score 4):

Another answer for those searching! If you are calling a *binary* and not a script, make sure it's built for the correct architecture (arm/x86) and that you can run it directly, which might show you the problem.

My binary was built for x86 and when I ran it on arm, the console error was `unexpected )` but this caused the binary to error, which caused systemd to log `Exec format error` which was nothing to do with the format in the service file.

Answer (score -1):

ExecStart=/bin/bash ... script.sh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).